# Error while getting the row count in mysql stored procedure for second time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure to insert data into tbluser table. Following is my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

  /* Check if user already exits*/
  DECLARE user_count INT;
  select count(*) from tblusers into user_count where name = 'joseph';  

  /* Calculate the row count of table and calculate the id for new row*/
  DECLARE totalrows,current_id INT;
  select count(*) from tblusers into totalrows; 
  SET current_id = totalrows + 1;

 /*Other part of procedure with insert statement*/

END
```

I am getting error name MYSQL 1064: at the line DECLARE totalrows,current_id INT; saying mysql syntax is wrong.If I am omitting the first two statements in the stored procedure, then it works fine.  Please correct me where am wrong, am new to using stored procedures in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare statements must be the first statement after the begin statement.  The first select is throwing it off. see:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html

Comment: but INT is a data type of the variable user_count ? Am I wrong in any sense

Comment: Yup, this answer is incorrect:  INT is, indeed, the data type.  I wonder if MySQL doesn't like the placement of the statement.  What if you moved it next to the other DECLARE, so that there is no longer an SQL-statement between the two?

Comment: Clarified my question. Thanks a lot RIch